# Python using dictionary or list as user input

Tags: python

I use the dictionary at the very bottom to call a function with user input.

I want use a dictionary, list or any other solution to have the user to input the value for `rds_cluster_name`. This is the line in question `DBClusterIdentifier = rds_cluster_name.input("RDS cluster name: ")`

When I do the above I get the error `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'input'`.

So I run the script and a value from here must be inputted `funct_dict = {'start':start, 'stop':stop, 'status':status}`, if the function `status` is called, the cluster name must be passed.

I can do this when I declare the variable `rds_cluster_name = input("RDS Cluster: ")` and it will work, but they have to know the cluster name,  I want users to see a list or something like this `Choose cluster_name ('staging-cluster':1,'qa-cluster-1':2,'int1-cluster':3)` and they just to type down the number which correspond to the cluster name to be used.

How Can I accomplish this?.

```
rds_cluster_name = {'staging-cluster':1,'qa-cluster-1':2,'int1-cluster':3}

def status():
    rds_client = boto3.client('rds')
    response = rds_client.describe_db_clusters(
        DBClusterIdentifier = rds_cluster_name.input("RDS cluster name: "),
        MaxRecords=20,
    )
    status = response['DBClusters'][0]['Status']
    status = status.upper()
    print(f' RDS cluster "{rds_cluster_name}" is: {status}')

funct_dict = {'start':start, 'stop':stop, 'status':status}
if __name__ == "__main__":

    command = input("Input action: ")
try:
    funct_dict[command]()
except KeyError:
    print(f'Command "{command}" is unknown. Only values accepted are: start, stop or status')
```

Comment: You are calling `input()` as a function on the dict `rds_cluster_name`, where I think it should be used as a key instead. Try doing this: `DBClusterIdentifier = rds_cluster_name[input('RDS cluster name: ')]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ANSWERING TO MYSELF**

I have managed to accomplish what I needed, the code was a bit different than I initially imagine it, but I'm not surprise as I'm learning Python and everything is new to me :-)

The variable that before I wanted to call `rds_cluster_name`, now I call `cluster_dict`.

If you scroll down you will find this `cluster_dict = cluster_dict[x]['name']` and at that line is when the variable get loaded with the new value that the user has chosen from list.

I had a lot fun learning this, hopefully this help someone else, cheers.

```
# My dict variable with items numbered
#
cluster_dict = {
    1: {'name': 'staging-cluster'},
    2: {'name': 'qa-cluster-1'},
    3: {'name': 'int1-cluster'}
}
print("Cluster to be chosen")
# Printing out the content of the variable
#
for x, y in cluster_dict.items():
    print(x, ':', cluster_dict[x]['name'])

while True:
    print("\nSelect a Cluster:")
    # Right user input, all I needed
    #
    x = int(input())
    
    # And here, if it is right just "break" out of the while, if not go back to iterate
    #
    if x in cluster_dict.keys():
        x = int(x)
        print("\nYou have chosen: {0}".format(cluster_dict[x]['name']))
        print("\n")
        # At this point is where the variable is loaded with the value chosen by the user
        #
        cluster_dict = cluster_dict[x]['name']
        break
    
    else:
        print('\nNumber not in list, try again!')
```

Answer (score 1):

I might be getting something wrong, but I don't think that `dict`s has an `input` attribute.  You might be trying to get a dictionary key based on input, in which case:

```py
DBClusterIdentifier = rds_cluster_name[input("RDS cluster name: ")]
```

This will set `DBClusterIdentifier` to `rds_cluster_name["whatever they inputted"]` (which should be `staging-cluster`, `qa-cluster-1`, or `int1-cluster`, setting `DBClusterIdentifier` to `1`, `2`, or `3` respectively).

Comment: You are right, dict has not input attribute, I was just trying different options as I am a beginner with Pyhton, thanks for you input

Comment: @farp332 : You are welcome!  If this answers your question, you can upvote it and mark it as accepted.